# java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fws.ifisd.applet.MainApplet.class

Tags: java, applet, classnotfoundexception, lang

Hi im trying to use      http://ivip.ausirisfutures.com/

but  got folowing 
Aplication Error

anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance!
details says:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: fws.ifisd.applet.MainApplet.class
at sun.plugin2.applet.Applet2ClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass0(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2ClassLoader.loadCode(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager.initAppletAdapter(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
```

Comment: Obviously it doesn't find a class, but we can't answer properly without seeing the code which causes the exception

Comment: You set a high bar for people trying to help when you link to a page that makes a pop-up with frames before they can see the problem.  Link *directly* to the page containing the applet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> anyone know how to fix it?

It should be up to you to fix it.  Contact the site owners and report the problem to them.

Personally, I'd stay clear of this site.  Any public site that (still) uses Java applets should be treated with great suspicion, especially if you have no way of assessing their trustworthiness and their ability to secure their site.  Consider how many security problems have been reported recently with Java browser plugins.